# Removing data from a list from a raw_input variable

Tags: python

So I'm fairly new to Python. After going through a few different tutorials and such I've decided to try and make a simple program, one of the things in it I need it to remove a line in a txt file. Here's the code I currently have:

```
    name = raw_input("What name would you like to remove: ")
    templist = open("oplist.txt").readlines()
    templist_index = templist.index(name)
    templist.remove(templist_index)
    target = open("oplist.txt", "w")
    target.write(templist)
    target.close
```

However when templist is made it stores the data like "example1\n" which if the user only typed example it wouldn't work. Is there any simpler ways to this or fix? Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `rstrip` to remove the newlines chars and use `with` to open your files:

```
with open("oplist.txt") as f: # with opens and closes the file automtically
    templist = [x.rstrip() for x in f] # strip new line char from every word
```

You could also concat a newline char to name:

```
templist_index = templist.index(name+"\n") # "foo" -> "foo\n"
```

The full code:

```
with open("oplist.txt") as f:
    temp_list = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    name = raw_input("What name would you like to remove: ")
    temp_list.remove(name) # just pass name no need for intermediate variable
    with open("oplist.txt", "w") as target: # reopen with w to overwrite
        for line in temp_list: # iterate over updated list
             target.write("{}\n".format(line)) # we need to add back in the new line 
                                                # chars we stripped or all words will be on one line
```

Comment: Works good, thanks. Now I just have to learn how and why it works.

Comment: i will add some comments but it is doing nothing fancy

Comment: Yea, I can easily find out what's going on. Like I said earlier, I'm still a beginner :P

Comment: added a few comments, hopefully makes it more transparent